# addOnPageChangeListener not working the first time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a recyclerview and a floating action button in my main activity. I have two viewpager fragments with nothing but a linearlayout. In **addOnPageChangeListener**, i'm adding a listener which populates recyclerview and implements onItemClick on floating action button when TAB 1 is selected and only populating the recyclerview and hiding the fab when TAB 2 is selected. 
In my two fragments, i've nothing but inflated the respective layouts.

When i open the activity, the recyclerview is empty. When i select the other tab, the recyclerview starts working and populates the other tab TAB 2. When i select the TAB 1 now, it also gets populated as expected and clickListener on fab also works as expected.

But why is it that the recyclerview is empty the first time around. The swipe also doesn't work. Any solutions? I am not creating recyclerview in each of the fragments since i've to update it using fab button. And my fab button is in the mainActivity. I don't want to put the fab button in the first fragment only since that would mean the default fab animation will be gone, when swiping through fragments.

http://pastebin.com/rrumZyf4

Comment: The code is quite long. Please suggest a general technique to show the recycler view on opening the activity.

Comment: are you initializing your code in onCreate() method??

Comment: add relevant part of the code if not complete

Comment: Added the relevant part of code. addOnPageChangeListener is in the onCreate()

Answer (score 2):

Little late to join the party but you can do something like this ..

```
mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            boolean first = true;

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset,
                    final int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (first && positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0){
                    onPageSelected(0);
                    first = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
                setItem(item.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {

            }
        });
```

Inside onPageScrolled method, you can check whether its the first item or not and set the page accordingly. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are loading data from server only inside the `onPageSelected` method. This will not trigger the first time `viewpager` loads. Only when the page is changed. 
You will have to make the initial data load outside this method.

Comment: yeah, you got the point. Yes, i can load data outside the method but is there any other better option because that would mean repeating a lot of code. and what is the reason behind the tab swipe not working?

Comment: Put it as a separate method. Call it where you need.

Comment: Reloading data from server every time tab is changed is a bad option by the way.

Comment: yes, i agree. so, the best option would be to have seperate recyclerviews for both fragments? But then how would i implement onClickListener on fab because it is in mainActivity anchored to the viewpager and i've to add elements to the recycler in the first TAB after the action taken on clicking fab. should i implement fab also in the fragment of first TAB. would that be a good practice?

Comment: If you need to show different list content for each tab, then better to include recyclerview in each fragment. For changing list item inside fragment check this [Deliver a Message to a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver)